# Better coordinates for maximally extended Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: differential-geometry, numerical-methods, manifolds, coordinate-systems, general-relativity

There are [many possible coordinate systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric#Alternative_coordinates) for describing the Schwarzschild spacetime. [Eddington–Finkelstein (EF) coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington%E2%80%93Finkelstein_coordinates) have an especially simple form:

$$ ds^2 = -\left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right) du^2 + 2 du \, dr + r^2 g_\Omega $$

where $g_\Omega = d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d \varphi^2$ is the standard 2-sphere metric in spherical coordinates. Unfortunately, EF coordinates are not regular across the past (white hole) horizon. The same is true for [Gullstrand–Painlevé (GP) coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullstrand%E2%80%93Painlev%C3%A9_coordinates).

[Kruskal–Szekeres (KS) coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates) have the advantage that they cover the *entire* manifold of the maximally extended Schwarzschild spacetime, and are well-behaved everywhere outside the physical singularity. The disadvantage is that they are more complex. For instance, their expression needs the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

My question is this: Is there any coordinate system which, like KS, covers the entire maximally extended spacetime but retains a level of simplicity comparable to EF coordinates? I'm especially interested in coordinate systems that are very well-suited for *numerical* computation and geodesic ray-tracing.